# Write message that can be verified by any member of a group

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature, asymmetric, iot

I am trying to develop a scheme for publishing a message to a group of recipients. Any recipient needs to be able to verify who the message was sent by.

There may be tens of messages generated each second, and the senders may be low power, embedded devices.

My understanding is there are two ways to achieve this:

1. Use asymmetric cryptography. Verify every message with a private key, and share the public key with each group member.
2. Separate keys for each member. Negotiate a separate symmetric key with every `m` members of the group, then sign every message `m` times using the symmetric key.

Are there any additional approaches I am missing?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Why not use already developed and well-reviewed protocols like Matrix?

Answer (score 1):

For efficient & secure group messaging, the distributed asynchronous [Messaging Layer Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messaging_Layer_Security)<sup>([0](https://youtu.be/FESp2LHd42U))([1](https://youtu.be/-45R8ObINyU))([2](https://youtu.be/Bjuokk1tGB0))</sup> (**MLS**) protocol was developed. According to **RFC 9420**, its efficiency *"allows the members of the group to derive and update shared keys with costs that scale as the log of the group size."*<sup>([3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9420.html))</sup> It achieves this by organizing members of a group into a logical tree, & doing [TreeKEM](https://inria.hal.science/hal-02425247/file/treekem%20(1).pdf) operations on the tree instead of on each leaf's public key.

[image: MLS efficiency comparisons against client-fanout, & sender-key based secure group management/messaging methods]

<sup>**Illustration 1:** MLS efficiency [comparisons](https://rwc.iacr.org/2019/slides/MLS%20@%20RWC%202019.pdf) against other secure group messaging & management methods.</sup>

---

> Any recipient needs to be able to verify who the message was sent by.

**MLS** is claimed to provide this. Particularly, the ability to have authentication & deniability together.<sup>([4](https://rwc.iacr.org/2019/slides/MLS%20@%20RWC%202019.pdf))</sup>

---

> 1. Use asymmetric cryptography. Verify every message with a private key, and share the public key with each group member.

This doesn't quite make sense. If only one private key is used to sign messages & only the public key is distributed to the group, then no one else would be able to sign messages.

Every member of the group could share the same private key, but this would be the same as sharing a symmetric key, only more computationally expensive<sup>([5](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/170038/289428))</sup>, & it wouldn't be able to reliably attest specifically to each sender.

Sharing the same static symmetric encryption key for the whole group, where each member had their own signing key<sup>([6](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/107625/89214))</sup>, would likely pull less power than **MLS**, but only if the keys are never updated. **MLS** solves the secure group-wise asymmetric key updating problem with **O(**log**(***n***))** complexity. If the keys aren't continuously updated, as **MLS** does, then the protocol won't provide [Post-Compromise Security](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7536374).

---

> 2. Separate keys for each member. Negotiate a separate symmetric key with every m members of the group, then sign every message m times using the symmetric key.

This doesn't scale well even without taking into account continuous key updating. So this is likely too costly for low-power / low-memory devices.

Comment: I assume approach 1 refers to each sender having their own private key, and sharing the public key with everybody. Which means O(n^2) public key instances out there, and adding or removing or rotating a key is an O(n) operation in a sense, but if your network is pretty static and not too large that's not necessarily infeasible. MLS sounds interesting though, and potentially strictly better except perhaps on constant factors (which may or may not matter depending on the size of n and the amount of compute on offer).

Comment: @CBHacking Mmm, yeah, that's possible. OP hasn't yet clarified the original intention of point 1 ***shrug***. MLS is cool. I'm honestly surprised that a standards body created such a high quality distributed e2ee group management / messaging protocol. I'd bet, in the long run, it still won't prove to be the optimal solution in terms of efficiency, but they've done a truly outstanding job on the security & privacy design.